# InfluxDB, Can I use the database files from an old installation, where raspbian chrashed during an update, on a new installation?

Tags: raspbian, influxdb

When updating raspbian on my PI3 some package failed and after that, reboot failed.
The green led doesn't even give a "blink" and nothing on the screen.
So I think I have to reinstall it. But then the whole card will be formatted.
As I have some measurements on the card I want to know if there is a way to restore the database on a new installation.
The card seems ok as I can read all files on it. I just have to copy /var/lib/influxdb to another computer.
But is it then possible to restore the data to a new installation?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I solved it.

1. I copied the influx directory (recursively)to another computer.
2. I installed a new OS on my PI3.
3. I copied the directory, again recursively, to /var/lib/on the new OS.
4. I Installed influxdb and started InfluxDB. Voila! The data was there!

Happy I am.
Thank's for watching!